# Case Sensitive collation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

Is there any Collation type in MySQL which supports Case Sensitive.
I had all type of collation in MySQL they all have _ci at the end of their name so they are case Insensitive collation.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

According to MySQL Manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html you should be able to set collation to `_cs` for case sensitivity. You can get a list of `_cs` collations by executing `SHOW COLLATION WHERE COLLATION LIKE  "%_cs"` query

---

After a little research:

Apparently there are no `utf8_*_cs` in MySQL (yet). If you need case sensitive collation for utf8 fields, you should use `utf8_bin`. This will mess up `ORDER BY`, but this can be fixed by `ORDER BY column COLLATE utf8_general_ci`

Source: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,19380,200971#msg-200971 and http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,156527,198794#msg-198794

Comment: `utf8mb4_bin` exists, too, since it's 2019 now :-)

Comment: To convert utf8 value to charset latin1 and then use latin1_general_cs for like-comparison use: select ... convert(cast(convert(myfield using utf8) as binary) using latin1) COLLATE latin1_general_cs like '...'

Answer (score 16):

Try a collation ending in `_bin`, such as `latin1_bin` or `utf8_bin`, depending on your character set.

Comment: Thanks Neil IT works when i set user column to utf8_bin it retrives only the data which is specified in query though i have the data with same word i mean Keyur,keyur,KEYUR. any way thanks.............

Answer (score 5):

The new version of MySQL (8.0.1 and higher) comes (finally) with a set of `utf8mb4_*_0900_as_cs` collations.

More about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-1-accent-and-case-sensitive-collations-for-utf8mb4/)