# Using the SQL LIKE operator with the UPPER() syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to use the LIKE operator in my query as follows:

```
mysql> select cat_title from category where cat_title like '%Indian%Restaurant%';
+--------------------+
| cat_title          |
+--------------------+
| Indian_Restaurants |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (2.59 sec)
```

However, since I want to do a case insensitive search, I am trying:

```
mysql> select cat_title from category where UPPER(cat_title) like UPPER('%Indian%Restaurant%');
Empty set (2.83 sec)
```

Why is the second query not working?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the collation on the `cat_title` column is case insensitive. Use

```
... cat_title LIKE '%Indian%Restaurant%' COLLATE utf8_bin
```

See also

- [How can I make SQL case sensitive string comparison on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql)
- [Case Sensitive collation in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558707/case-sensitive-collation-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

in all the sql there is ILIKE which is responsible to do case insensitive compression, so you can modify your query like below

```
select cat_title from category where cat_title ilike '%Indian%Restaurant%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's your question. The UPPER function won't work before a 'like' operator. If you want a case-insensitive search, use the operator 'like' only, since it's case-insensitive.

On the other hand, if you want a case-sensitive search, you may try using

```
   cat_title COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN LIKE '%Indian%Restaurant%'
```