# How to generate random yet unique string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, algorithm, hash, logic

I have defined valid characters set.
eg. [a,b,c,d,.......A,B,C,D,,.............0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
And I want to generate a **RANDOM** yet **UNIQUE** string in **PHP** .

Also i want to specify a length of output string.
Like. Generate **5 digit** output string from given character set.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558707/case-sensitive-collation-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On 5.6.13, the answer is:

```
mysql> SHOW COLLATION LIKE '%cs';
+--------------------+---------+----+---------+----------+---------+
| Collation          | Charset | Id | Default | Compiled | Sortlen |
+--------------------+---------+----+---------+----------+---------+
| latin1_general_cs  | latin1  | 49 |         | Yes      |       1 |
| latin2_czech_cs    | latin2  |  2 |         | Yes      |       4 |
| cp1250_czech_cs    | cp1250  | 34 |         | Yes      |       2 |
| latin7_estonian_cs | latin7  | 20 |         | Yes      |       1 |
| latin7_general_cs  | latin7  | 42 |         | Yes      |       1 |
| cp1251_general_cs  | cp1251  | 52 |         | Yes      |       1 |
+--------------------+---------+----+---------+----------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

or any `*_bin` Collation.

But first, what `CHARACTER SET` will you be using?