# Case sensitive unique constraints on django and mysql

Tags: mysql, django

I have a model with a unique constraint (or rather unique_together):

```
class ReadingMapping(models.Model):
    mapset = models.ForeignKey('mapping.ReadingMapset')
    data = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="attributes")

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('mapset', 'data')
```

However because I'm using MYSQL as backend, the comparison is case insensitive because of the collation/charset which is either a default of MYSQL or of Django (is this correct?) and I need it to be case sensitive.

From reading around I gathered this cannot be directly in the Django model, and so I need to alter the table on the database (See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558707/case-sensitive-collation-in-mysql))

My first question is what is the correct SQL statement to alter the table, or rather the column. I'm not sure if I need to change the charset or just the collation, or which charset/collation I should be setting it to despite reading various sources.

My second question is how do I make this change part of migrations (we'll have dozens of databases) can I just create an arbitrary migration file with an SQL statement in it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following to work in a migration file:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('mapping', '0003_auto_20170725_0737'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL("ALTER TABLE mapping_readingmapping CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs;")
    ]
```