# SQL: Finding rows containing phrases regardless of case

Tags: mysql, sql, natural-join

Here is the database I'm using: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ArJekOQpal0JFIr1h3NXYcFVngnCNUxg/view?usp=sharing

**List the deptnum and total number of academics for CS departments, in
alphabetical order of deptname. CS departments are departments whose deptname
contains the phrase "Computer ... Science" or “Computing … Science” in upper case or
lower case letters. You must use the NATURAL JOIN operator.**

My attempt at this question:

```
SELECT deptnum
FROM academic NATURAL JOIN department
WHERE UPPER(deptname) LIKE ('%computer science%') OR UPPER(deptname) LIKE 
('%computing science%')
ORDER BY deptnum;
```

It keeps coming up with no values, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you

EDIT:

Thanks everyone. This is what I'm using now (although inefficient):

```
SELECT distinct deptnum
FROM academic NATURAL JOIN department
WHERE UPPER(deptname) LIKE ('%COMPUTER%') AND UPPER(deptname) LIKE 
('%SCIENCE%')OR UPPER(deptname) LIKE ('%COMPUTING%') AND UPPER(deptname) 
LIKE ('%SCIENCE%')
ORDER BY deptnum;
```

Comment: jump to `sqlfiddle.com` or `rextester.com`

Comment: `UPPER(deptname) LIKE ('%COMPUTER%') OR UPPER(deptname) LIKE 
('%COMPUTING SCIENCE%')`  since you want to match against UPPER CASE

Comment: Your database (google drive link) need access permission, share it before post link to it

Comment: I updated my original post with a shareable link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ArJekOQpal0JFIr1h3NXYcFVngnCNUxg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Thanks that worked, however I'm missing a few queries. It doesn't seem to output deptnames such as "School of Computer and Information Science", even though it contains "computer science"

Comment: nvm, I found a way to output it, although it seems a bit long and inefficient:

SELECT distinct deptnum
FROM academic NATURAL JOIN department
WHERE UPPER(deptname) LIKE ('%COMPUTER%') AND UPPER(deptname) LIKE ('%SCIENCE%')OR UPPER(deptname) LIKE ('%COMPUTING%') AND UPPER(deptname) LIKE ('%SCIENCE%')
ORDER BY deptnum;

Comment: Check your database collations i guess they are set as case sensitive, Have a look at [Case Sensitive collation in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558707/case-sensitive-collation-in-mysql) and [10.2 Character Sets and Collations in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-mysql.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `LIKE` operator in MySQL is already case insensitive, so the following should work:

```
SELECT deptnum
FROM academic
NATURAL JOIN department
WHERE deptname LIKE '%computer%' OR deptname LIKE '%computing science%'
ORDER BY deptnum;
```

We can tidy this up a bit by using `REGEXP`, which is also case insensitive:

```
SELECT deptnum
FROM academic
NATURAL JOIN department
WHERE deptname REGEXP 'computer|computing science'
ORDER BY deptnum;
```