# SQL: How to create table with case sensitive for unique key for utf8mb4_general_ci?

Tags: sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I am using phpMyAdmin and PDO.
My database using utf8mb4_general_ci.
And look like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `my_database`.`example` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `code` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE (`code`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I got an error when I inserted 'A' and 'a'.
I fix it by changing the Collation of the `code` column to utf8mb4_bin.

Have any way to use utf8mb4_general_ci with sensitive cases?
Can I set it in phpMyAdmin, PDO, or SQL?

Comment: `Have any way to use utf8mb4_general_ci with sensitive cases?` The `_ci` stands for case insensitive, so no.

Comment: Aww, thank you for the new thing. Do you have any collate recommendations to use instead utf8_general_ci?
I don't see menu utf8mb4_general_cs in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558707/case-sensitive-collation-in-mysql See the (currently) last post.

Comment: I see my answer now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank @tkausl and @topsail.

The `utf8mb4_general_ci` contain `_ci` that for case insensitive.

From [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558707/case-sensitive-collation-in-mysql](https://case-sensitive-collation-in-mysql),
I should use `utf8mb4_bin` for the unique column that I want case sensitive and I can use `ORDER BY column COLLATE utf8_general_ci`.